# product of integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f,g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ Riemann integrable and bounded. We then know that $fg$ is also integrable. I wonder if the statement remains true or not under the following weakenings of the hypotheses ($f$ and $g$ are always integrable):

1) $f$ bounded but $g$ unbounded?

2) $f,g$ bounded but defined on $\mathbb{R}$ or on unbounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$? Does $fg$ remain integrable on $\mathbb{R}$? (Note that a function not integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ can be integrable on compact sets, like $f(x)=x$).

Comment: An unbounded function will have infinite Riemann sums, or what is your definition?

Comment: For example $1/\sqrt{x}$ is unbounded but integrable on $[0,1]$

Answer (score 1):

For 2), consider $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt x}\sin x$ (for $x>1$ and $0$ for $x\le 1$). Then the convergence of $\int_{\Bbb R}$ follows from the Leibniz criterion for alternating series. But with $g=f$, we see that the integral of $fg$ does not converge because it behaves like the harmonic series.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, the criterion only provides conditional convergence, while I do not see absolute convergence, which is what should be needed. In other words, it seems that the integral of f you propose is not independent on the rearrangements of the sum of positive and negative pieces (like 1-1/2+1/3-1/4+... etc.)

Answer (score 0):

1) and 2) are both true by Holder's inequality if this holds also for Riemann integral. Let $\Omega$ be the domain of integration. Then $$||fg||_{L^{1}(\Omega)}\leq ||f||_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}||g||_{L^{1}(\Omega)}$$ This should hold also for Riemann integral (?)